# Set the scrollbar of a div to the top

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have created a custom CSS modal. Inside the modal, there is a scrollable div(the modal itself is not scrollable). When I first open the modal, the scrollbar of the div is set to the top as expected. Now, if I scroll, close the modal, and open it again, the scrollbar is at its previous position. But I expect it on the top every time I open it.

Here is the CSS code of the modal

```
.create-modal-content {
        position: relative;
        background-color: #F7F7F8;
        margin: auto;
        padding: 0;
        border: 1px solid #888;
        width: 95%;
        height: 95%;
        border-radius: 5px;
        box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
        animation-name: createAnimation;
    }

    @keyframes createAnimation {
        from {
            right: 0;
            opacity: 0
        }
        to {
            right: 0;
            opacity: 1
        }
    }
```

The code for the scrollable div is

```
    .create-container {
        background-color: #e7e7e7;
        margin: 35px 15px 0 15px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        max-height: 70vh;
        overflow: auto;
    }
```

The whole html, css code for the modal and the div is

```
<div class="create-modal-content" >
  <div class="ml-12 mt-24 font-size-18 font-weight-700">Create Organization</div>
  <div fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayout.xs="column" fxLayoutGap="15px" class="pl-48 pt-12 pb-12   create-container">
    <input type="file" accept="image/*" hidden #fileInput (change)="imageSelected($event )" />
   </div>
               
   <div fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="end center">
    <button class="mt-12 mb-12" mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="saveOrganization()">
         Edit
    </button>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Here is the typescript part where I tried both querySelector and getElementByClassName. But none of them seem to work

```
const modal = document.getElementById('organization');
        modal.style.display = 'block';
        const createContainer = modal.getElementsByClassName('create-container')[0];
        // const createContainer = modal.querySelector(".create-container");
        modal.addEventListener('click', function() {
            createContainer.scrollTop = 0;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use scrollTo(x, y)

```
modal.addEventListener('click', function() {
    createContainer.scrollTo(0, 0);
});
```